# How to make SelectListItem Selected true or false on based on condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Here is my Model

```
  public class NewsViewModel
    {
        public NewsViewModel()
        {

            this.Categories = new List<Category>();

        }
        public int NewsId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter News Title")]
        public string NewsTitle { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }


    }
```

I need to set Selected to be True if id exists in NewsViewModel.Categories collection

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCategories()
{

    return db.Categories .Select(s=>new SelectListItem {
        Value=s.Id.ToString(),
        Text=s.Name,
        Selected = model.Categories.Select(x => x.CategoryId).Contains(s.CategoryId);

}
```

And in View:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(s => s.SelectedCategoriesIds, @Model.AllCategories, new { id = "DropDownList2", multiple = "multiple", @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: You have an open bracket without a close bracket in your second code snippet FYI.

Comment: Also, what's the problem with what you have now? Are you getting an error? Is it just not returning what you want?

Comment: @ChrisH. i get error 
Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Assignment.Category'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: The question is why are you wanting to set the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem`? If you are using `Html.DropDownListFor()` of `Html.ListBoxFor()` in your view (which you should be doing), then the `Selected` property is ignored - its the value of the property your binding to that determines what is selected (internally the methods build a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` based on the value(s) in the property)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you for help :) Can you please tell me how can i use Html.ListBoxFor() in View to achieve what you are saying.. Thank you

Comment: @StephenMuecke Here is my code ... You can use it to make it selected value true

Html.ListBoxFor(s => s.SelectedCategoriesIds, Model.AllCategories, new { id = "DropDownList2", multiple = "multiple", class = "form-control" })

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gHGaTy) for an example. Note there is no need for `multiple = "multiple"`. And to prove that setting the `Selected` property has no effect, comment out the line in the controller that sets `Selected=true` for all `SelectListItem`'s and run it again - note that it makes no difference at all - its the value of `SelectedCategories` which determines what is selected.

Answer (score 3):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405568/linq-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-xxx-only-primitive-types-or-enu); you cannot use `Contains` with non-primitive types (like `Category` in this case). A different way to write your query that works around this limitation would be:

```
return db.Categories.Select(s=>new SelectListItem {
    Value=s.Id.ToString(),
    Text=s.Name,
    Selected = model.Categories.Exists(z => z.CategoryId == s.CategoryId);
}
```

Instead of selecting the `CategoryId`s from `model.Categories` and then checking if `s.CategoryId` is in that list, we can check to see if there `Exists()` an item in `model.Categories` for which the `CategoryId` is the same as `s.CategoryId`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the condition on the "selected" as a question mark condition.

```
    var listSiteId = (from site in db.GetSiteId().ToList()
                                      select new SelectListItem
                                      {
                                          Value = site.SITEID,
                                          Text = site.NAME,
                                          Selected = (dimension.DISPLAYVALUE == site.SITEID) ? true : false,
                                      }).ToList();
                    ViewBag.SiteId = listSiteId;
```